# Can not found file Xml comment in Web API(.NET 5 web API)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, .net-5, webapi, xml-comments

This is a picture of the code config file path of XML comment file.
[image]

When I deploy in Azure, I have a problem that It can't find this XML file
[image]

Comment: I try to add XML file into a wwwroot folder and it's not working too...someones meets this case like me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML comments can be enabled with the following approaches:

Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select Edit <project_name>.csproj.
Manually add the highlighted lines to the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>





public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         .......//swagger config..
     var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

Then you can read the xml:
[image]